# LDAP Authentication Without a Separate Login Page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, authentication, ldap

I have an MVC 4 project that currently authenticates credentials that the user enters when they reach the Account view. I'd rather supply the credentials using the credentials they used to log onto the network and ditch the Account view all together.

How would I accomplish this?

Thanks.

Comment: Is this ASP.NET MVC? And Windows networking? If so, you would do this by setting `Authentication Mode="Windows"` in your web.config.

Comment: Thank you I will give that a shot. Would be nice to be that straight forward.